# How to Sort Integer Strings?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I am facing a strange problem while sorting a list of strings with integer values. However some values could be prefixed with some characters.

e.g.

```
// B1, 5, 50, A10, 7, 72, B3, A1, A2
```

There are basically page numbers and should be sorted like:

```
// A1, A2, A10, B1, B3, 5, 7, 50, 72
```

But if I use default string sorting then these will be sorted like

```
// A1, A10, A2, B1, B3, 5, 50, 7, 72
```

Any solution for this in C#?

Comment: You can use this `NaturalStringComparer` that I put together and cleaned up a bit (Don't remember where I got the basis for it). It uses the Win32 function StrCmpLogicalW that Skizz mentions. http://my.opera.com/Svishy/blog/2009/03/02/natural-sorting

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're looking for the **[Alphanum algorithm](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html)**. Fortunately for you, a number of implementations exist already. See **[here](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html)**.

Comment: Alphanum will return // 5, 7, 50, 72, A1, A2, A10, B1, B3 instead of // A1 ... 5

Comment: If you go through some of the code samples, it's outlined how you'd change it to accomodate subtly different scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I solved it for our application, order will be like in a windows directory:

```
public class NaturalSortComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return StrCmpLogicalW(x, y);
    }

    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string x, string y);
}
```

Usage:

```
  NaturalSortComparer comparer = new NaturalSortComparer();
  return comparer.Compare(string1, string2);
```

But it's probably not exactly what you want:

> // A1, A2, A10, B1, B3, 5, 7, 50, 72

This will give

> // 5, 7, 50, 72, A1, A2, A10, B1, B3

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a Natural Sort.

Jeff Atwood made a great post on his blog once, explaining the concept and linking to various other sources with algorithms you could take as an example.

[Sorting for Humans : Natural Sort Order](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a custom comparer that will sort into your required order. *Note that there are no error/sanity checks in this code: it assumes that all the strings will be in the correct format.*

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        Match xMatch = Regex.Match(x, @"^(\D*)(\d+)$");
        Match yMatch = Regex.Match(y, @"^(\D*)(\d+)$");

        string xChars = xMatch.Groups[1].Value;
        string yChars = yMatch.Groups[1].Value;

        if ((xChars.Length == 0) && (yChars.Length > 0))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if ((xChars.Length > 0) && (yChars.Length == 0))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            int charsResult = xChars.CompareTo(yChars);

            return (charsResult != 0)
                ? charsResult
                : int.Parse(xMatch.Groups[2].Value)
                    .CompareTo(int.Parse(yMatch.Groups[2].Value));
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
List<string> testList =
    new List<string>() { "B1","5","50","A10","7","72","B3","A1","A2" };

testList.Sort(new MyComparer());    // A1, A2, A10, B1, B3, 5, 7, 50, 72
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always pInvoke the Win32 API function `StrCmpLogicalW` which does exactly what you want (it's what Explorer uses to sort filenames). The only possible downside is that the sort is case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about performance, and sure this can be optimized, but it do the work:

```
string[] sort(string[] data)
{
    return data
        .OrderBy(s => Regex.Match(s, @"^\D").Length == 0)
        .ThenBy(s => Regex.Match(s, @"\D*").Value)
       .ThenBy(s => Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(s, @"\d+").Value)).ToArray();
}

var result = sort(new string[] { "B1", "5", "50", "A10", "7", "72", "B3", "A1", "A2" });
```