# How to order the XML Element by name

Tags: c#

I need to order the xmlelement by element name. Below i mentioned my before arrange and after arrange the file.

File datas like:

```
  <Root>
       <RB-3-10  K="3" P="0.5" L="5" G="5.5" E="3" l="5" O="2.5" />
       <RB-4-6   K="3" P="0.5" L="6" G="5.5" E="3" l="6" O="2.5" />
       <RB-3-5   K="3" P="0.5" L="10" G="5.5" E="3" l="10" O="2.5" />
       <RB-3-12  K="3" P="0.5" L="12" G="5.5" E="3" l="12" O="2.5" />
       <RB-4-14  K="3" P="0.5" L="14" G="5.5" E="3" l="14" O="2.5" />
       <RB-3-15  K="3" P="0.5" L="15" G="5.5" E="3" l="15" O="2.5" />
       <RB-5-16  K="3" P="0.5" L="16" G="5.5" E="3" l="16" O="2.5" />
  </Root>
```

But I need output like

```
  <Root>
       <RB-3-5    K="3" P="0.5" L="10" G="5.5" E="3" l="10" O="2.5" />
       <RB-3-10   K="3" P="0.5" L="5" G="5.5" E="3" l="5" O="2.5" />
       <RB-3-12   K="3" P="0.5" L="12" G="5.5" E="3" l="12" O="2.5" />
       <RB-3-15   K="3" P="0.5" L="15" G="5.5" E="3" l="15" O="2.5" />
       <RB-4-6    K="3" P="0.5" L="6" G="5.5" E="3" l="6" O="2.5" />
       <RB-4-14   K="3" P="0.5" L="14" G="5.5" E="3" l="14" O="2.5" />
       <RB-5-16   K="3" P="0.5" L="16" G="5.5" E="3" l="16" O="2.5" /> 
  </Root>
```

Any can know how to sort element by it's name.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451987/sorting-xml-using-linq

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this (assuming that you have the same pattern in the element names):

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load("xml.xml");
        var ordered = xDoc.Root.Elements()
            .OrderBy(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Name.LocalName.Split('-')[1]))
            .ThenBy(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Name.LocalName.Split('-')[2]))
            .ToList();
        xDoc.Root.ReplaceAll(ordered);
        xDoc.Save("xml_1.xml");
    }
}
```

You could also use just one to `OrderBy` (without using `ThenBy`), but you have to know beforehand how large the integers could get in the XML tag names. Here's an example which assumes that there are no more than 2 digits.

```
var ordered = xDoc.Root.Elements()
    .OrderBy(i => Convert.ToInt32(
        i.Name.LocalName.Split('-')[1].PadLeft(2, '0') +
        i.Name.LocalName.Split('-')[2].PadLeft(2, '0')))
    .ToList();
```

**Last but not least**, here's a way to do it by using a `IComparer` implementation (credits should go to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/785430/674700)):

```
var ordered = xDoc.Root.Elements()
    .OrderBy(i => i.Name.LocalName, new NaturalSortComparer())
    .ToList();
```

The `NaturalSortComparer` class:

```
public class NaturalSortComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return StrCmpLogicalW(x, y);
    }

    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string x, string y);
}
```

Comment: thanks Mr.Alex Filipovici it's working fine..